# Using Redux to make a React component perform a one-time action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

Within a React component, I want to fire off an action to a Redux reducer that conducts an API call upon a button press.

Upon successfully executing this API call, I want my reducer to then dispatch to my component that the call has successfully executed.

My component will receive this dispatch as a prop (e.g. `this.props.successfullyUpdated`) and will render a window alert.

For example in my render function,

```
render() {
   if (this.props.successfullyUpdated) {
   return renderSuccessAlert();
   }
}
```

The issue that I'm facing is that I want this alert to be shown only once after every API execution. So after the alert is called, I don't want it called again until Redux dispatches another `successfullyUpdated` prop.

Right now, once `successfullyUpdated` is a part of the props, the alert continuously renders even though it was only dispatched once via Redux. How do I stop this from happening, and only render the alert on-demand?

Comment: well do you ever set succesfullyUpdated back to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a function that will set `successfullyUpdated` back to `false`.

Once we get into the `if` statement and `successfullyUpdated` evaluates to `true`, you need to set it to `false`.

```
render() {
   if (this.props.successfullyUpdated) {
       this.props.setUpdatedFalse();
       return renderSuccessAlert();
   }
}
```

Comment: What will setUpdatedFalse do? Props should be treated as immutable.

Comment: @BeardMagician setUpdatedFalse is a function in the parent it will set the state of successfullyUpdated to false inside the parent component which will stop the repeated alerts unless the button is pressed.